# Display a divider

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place this division in the center of the site. But it's not working. Any idea how can i place the division in the center?

HTML:

```
<div id="first">
    <img id="image1" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
    <img id="image2" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
    <img id="image3" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
    <img id="image4" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
    <img id="image5" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
    <img id="image6" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
    <img id="image7" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
    <img id="image8" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
    <img id="image9" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
    <img id="image10"src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#first
{
    top:-215px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 220px;
}
#first img 
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
```

JSFIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/trszrqfx/

Comment: How it should look exactly?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking here; What divider?

Comment: @suslov the same as in the fiddle but in the center of the website

Comment: @Brian divider: first

Comment: There is no divider, not in your code, not in your styles, and not in your fiddle.

Comment: There is only a div with 10 images inside it.

Comment: "it's not working" isn't a meaningful problem statement, we need to know the desired effect. How is it supposed to work? What is it supposed to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know exactly what you are trying to do, but I guess that you want to center the "divider"

```
#first
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 220px;
    margin:auto; //add this
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/trszrqfx/2/

Comment: `top: -215px;` won't do anything in his example.

Comment: My bad, i forgot to remove this line

Comment: @MichaelJackson if i want to manipulate the division left,right bottom, up what poperty to use?

Comment: You can use float:left to move to the left, float:right to move to the right, and padding-top:(specific_number)px to move from the top and padding-bottom to move from the bottom. Do this changes on #first div

Comment: @MichaelJackson if padding-bottom is not working..Any idea why? are maybe an alternative??

Comment: Remove the top: 215px; and insert margin-top:-(specificvalue).px. Example: margin-top:-20px;

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
#first
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 220px;
}
#first img 
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 5%
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```